# How to make custom Android Animations

Tags: android, android-animation

I know how to do pull to refresh but in the link below you will see on pull to refresh a parachute animation starts, I want to know how to do this any guidance would be helpful.Thanks!

Link: http://tubikstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Animation-Saily-by-Tubik-Studio-2.gif

Another Link with a rocket instead of parachute below:

Link: https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/800/0*MdQLuddtp_YUlNDv.gif

How to accomplish such a cool animation?

Comment: Check out [this](https://github.com/Yalantis/Phoenix) lib

Comment: Thanks for the lib, it looks promising.if you can tell this lib as answer then i will accept it

Answer (score 0):

To track the movement of your finger you can use MotionEvent. To animate a parachute use the Interpolator and Animator. To start tracking - mTargetView.getTop(). Hopefully this will help you.